# How do I locate which file has a keyerror in python?

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

i have written  a pre processing script in python that helps consolidating confidence. Below is my script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import glob as glob


inp_dir = Path(r'C:/Users/jtharian/Desktop/bbc/') 

for file in inp_dir.glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', quotechar='|',error_bad_lines=False)
    df['confidence'] = df['confidence'].replace(np.nan, 0.01)
    df.to_csv(file,index=False)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\jtharian\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'confidence'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-0cbf17caf540>", line 11, in <module>
    df['confidence'] = df['confidence'].replace(np.nan, 0.01)

  File "C:\Users\jtharian\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "C:\Users\jtharian\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'confidence'
```

I unferstand I am receiving this error because one of the files in my directory does not have the column 'confidence'. But how can I locate that file or print the file name?

Comment: when you read the csv in df, check if column *confidence* exist!! like ```if 'confidence' in df.columns``` and you have the `file` variable, print it.

Comment: Put `print(file)` at the beginning of the loop. The problem is in the filename printed before the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe check the column names has `confidence` listed and break if not...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import glob as glob


inp_dir = Path(r'C:/Users/jtharian/Desktop/bbc/') 

for file in inp_dir.glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', quotechar='|',error_bad_lines=False)
    if 'confidence' not in df.columns:
        print('filename: ' + str(file))
        break
    df['confidence'] = df['confidence'].replace(np.nan, 0.01)
    df.to_csv(file,index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `try` and `exception` case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import glob as glob


inp_dir = Path(r'C:/Users/jtharian/Desktop/bbc/') 

for file in inp_dir.glob('*.csv'):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', quotechar='|',error_bad_lines=False)
        df['confidence'] = df['confidence'].replace(np.nan, 0.01)
        df.to_csv(file,index=False)
    except:
        # assumes error is known
        print("Invalid column in file:", file)
```

You can also use [sys module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) to get error output with the exception.

Comment: Note, it's good practice to specify which error to catch in the `except` field (e.g `except KeyError:`) to avoid catching other errors.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to print the file you're working on.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import glob as glob


inp_dir = Path(r'C:/Users/jtharian/Desktop/bbc/') 

for file in inp_dir.glob('*.csv'):
    print(f"Reading: {file}")
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', quotechar='|',error_bad_lines=False)
    df['confidence'] = df['confidence'].replace(np.nan, 0.01)
    df.to_csv(file,index=False)
```